# Lua: Line breaks in strings

Tags: string, lua

I've been working on a formatter that will take a long string and format it into a series of lines broken off at the word within a certain character limit. For instance, **He eats the bread**, broken off at every 8 characters, would return something like:

```
He eats
the
bread
```

This is because "He eats" contains 7 characters, and "the bread" contains 9, so it has to break off at "the" and continue with "bread".

The script itself has been working wonderfully, thanks to the help of other members before. However, now I have a new challenge.

I'm utilizing a free-entry box for entering the series of lines. It's for a program called MUSHclient, if anyone is familiar with it. The **utils.editbox** opens up an editor text box, and allows free form, and returns the result as a **string**. For example:

```
result = utils.editbox("What are you typing?")
```

saves the typed response into `result` which is a `string` type. I want to put line breaks in properly, but I can't figure out how to do that. If I `print(result)`, it returns something like the following:

```
This is the result of three separate paragraphs.

As you can see, there is a line break between each paragraph.

So the result contains line breaks, or control characters.
```

Now, I've managed to extrapolate the individual lines, but not the linebreaks in between, using the following code:

```
for line in result:gmatch("[^%c]+%c?") do 
  Send(note_wrap(line))
end
```

How can I extrapolate for linebreaks as well as textual content?

**Edit** For reference, the `note_wrap` function is as follows:

```
function note_wrap(str, limit, indent, indent1)
  indent = indent or ""
  indent1 = indent1 or indent
  limit = limit or 79
  local here = 1-#indent1
  local last_color = ''
  return indent1..str:gsub("(%s+)()(%S+)()",
    function(sp, st, word, fi)
      local delta = 0
      local color_before_current_word = last_color
      word:gsub('()@([@%a])', 
        function(pos, c)
          if c == '@' then 
            delta = delta + 1 
          elseif c == 'x' then 
            delta = delta + 5
            last_color = word:sub(pos, pos+4)
          else                 
            delta = delta + 2 
            last_color = word:sub(pos, pos+1)
          end
        end)
      here = here + delta
      if fi-here > limit then
        here = st - #indent + delta
        return "\n"..indent..color_before_current_word..word
      end
    end)
end
```

The reason for this code is to be able to take **@rHe eats @x123the bread**, ignore the color codes (indicated by @<letter> or @x<digits>) and return the aforementioned result of:

```
He eats
the
bread
```

but insert the color codes so it then returns:

```
@rHe eats
@x123the
bread
```

If this can be modified to recognize new lines and put an actual new line in, that would be fabulous.

**Edit 2** Tried Paul's solution, and it's not doing what I'm needing it to. I may not have been clear enough, so I'll try to clear it up in this edit.

When I type into the free form box, I want the information presented exactly as is, but formatted to break correctly AND maintain entered newlines. For example, if I write this in the free form box:

```
Mary had a little lamb, little lamb, little lamb
Mary had a little lamb
It's fleece was white as snow
```

using Paul's code, and setting string to 79, I get:

```
Mary had a little lamb, little lamb, little lamb

Mary had a little lamb

It's fleece was white as snow
```

And that's not what I want. I'd want it to return it just as it was written, and breaking line as necessary. So if I had a 20 character limit, it'd return:

```
Mary had a little
lamb, little lamb,
little lamb
Mary had a little
lamb
It's fleece was
white as snow
```

If I added manual line breaks, I'd want it to respect those, so if I hit return twice after the first line, it'd have a line break under the first line as well. For example, if I wrote this post in the free form box, I'd want it to respect every new paragraph and every proper line break as well. I hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this in my code (this assumes that `\n` is the line separator):

```
local function formatUpToX(s, x, indent)
  x = x or 79
  indent = indent or ""
  local t = {""}
  local function cleanse(s) return s:gsub("@x%d%d%d",""):gsub("@r","") end
  for prefix, word, suffix, newline in s:gmatch("([ \t]*)(%S*)([ \t]*)(\n?)") do
    if #(cleanse(t[#t])) + #prefix + #cleanse(word) > x and #t > 0 then
      table.insert(t, word..suffix) -- add new element
    else -- add to the last element
      t[#t] = t[#t]..prefix..word..suffix
    end
    if #newline > 0 then table.insert(t, "") end
  end
  return indent..table.concat(t, "\n"..indent)
end
print(formatUpToX(result, 20))
print(formatUpToX("@rHe eats @x123the bread", 8, "  "))
```

The `cleanse` function removes any markup that needs to be included in the string, but doesn't need to count against the limit.

For the example you have, I get the following output (using `20` as the limit for the first fragment and `8` for the second):

```
This is the result 
of three separate 
paragraphs.

As you can see, 
there is a line 
break between each 
paragraph.

So the result 
contains line 
breaks, or control 
characters.

  @rHe eats 
  @x123the 
  bread
```

Comment: Let me provide you with the format code I currently have. Perhaps you can modify that so that it'll break where it's supposed to break. I'd use yours, but there would need to be more modification. See edit in a few. And thanks so far!

Comment: If you just want to make sure that `@r` and `@xNNN` are not counted against the line limit, that should be easy to add; I'll update the post shortly.

Comment: I also added indent similar to the one you have (it's not included in the limit). If you need `indent1`, you can simply prepend it to the result.

Comment: I made another edit. I tried your code, and it still added extra blank lines where there needn't be. Plus, it didn't even format one line properly, and went over the limit. I appreciate all you're putting into this, by the way!

Comment: Josh, I get no blank lines added and the formatting is exactly as you'd expect: `formatUpToX("Mary had a little lamb, little lamb, little lamb\nMary had a little lamb\nIt's fleece was white as snow", 20) == "Mary had a little \nlamb, little lamb, \nlittle lamb\nMary had a little \nlamb\nIt's fleece was \nwhite as snow")`. Can you post a test that fails for you using my function?

Comment: It must be something with the editbox function then, and I'm wondering if it's adding secondary `\n` to the end of each line, because if I run it straight, then it works, but if I run it out of the editbox function (which I don't have access to view), it kicks in the extra newline.

Comment: It may be using `\r` instead of `\n` (or in addition to `\n`). You may want to change `\n?` in `gmatch` to `\r?\n?` or something similar. You may need to find out what code is really added by `editbox`.

Comment: Seems like I may need to do that then, because I just tried your suggestion, and it failed. I'll contact the author and find out. Thanks for the excellent work thus far though! I'll accept yours as the answer just because it theoretically works, just not in my case.

Comment: Bah, it was my fault on it adding extra line breaks when there should be single. However, it still doesn't respect extra line breaks that should be there. For example, `Mary had a little lamb\n\nIts fleece was white as snow\n\n` should return spaces between.

Comment: Josh, do you have a test case that fails for you? This works for me: `formatUpToX("Mary had a little lamb\n\nIts fleece was white as snow\n\n", 20) == "Mary had a little \nlamb\n\nIts fleece was white \nas snow\n\n"`.

Comment: I'm going to have to see what editbox does. For whatever reason or another, it works externally, but not with editbox. Thanks again, Paul!