# Split string into table in groups of 26 characters or less, rounded to the nearest word

Tags: string, lua

I'm trying to take a string and split it into a table, with each index containing a maximum of 26 characters, but words are not split between indices. If it stretches over 26 characters mid-word, that word is in the next index.

Answer (score 0):

I've [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35007058/1442917) some time ago; I'm sure you can get the suggested implementation and use it for your case. You just need to return the table instead of doing the concatenation:

```
local function formatUpToX(s)
  local x = 26
  local splitstr = "([ \t]*)(%S*)([ \t]*)(\n?)"
  local t = {""}
  for prefix, word, suffix, newline in s:gmatch(splitstr) do
    if #(t[#t]) + #prefix + #word > x and #t > 0 then
      table.insert(t, word..suffix)
    else
      t[#t] = t[#t]..prefix..word..suffix
    end
    if #newline > 0 then table.insert(t, "") end
  end
  return t
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Words longer than `wrap_length` are the only words that will overflow, but that behavior can be customized by replacing `or str:find'%s'`.

```
local function wrap_string(str, wrap_length)
  local lines = {}

  while #str > 0 do
    local last_space_index

    -- Only check substrings longer than the wrap length
    if #str > wrap_length then
      -- Check for first space so words longer than `wrap_length` don't break.
      last_space_index = str:sub(1, wrap_length):find'%s%S*$' or str:find'%s'
    end

    table.insert(lines, str:sub(1, last_space_index))

    if not last_space_index then break end

    str = str:sub(last_space_index + 1)
  end
  return lines
end
```